# Get Value From table when on Click of Button using jQuery

Tags: jquery

This is my Code as given below. Here table shows date time string and Close button. When i click on close button it removes concern row. but before removing i need date in variable.

```js
$(document).on('click', 'button.removebutton', function () {
 alpha = $(this).closest('tr #newdate').val();
 alert(alpha);
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="schedule"> 
 <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="newdate" id="newdate" value="2017-06-26">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="newtime" id="newtime" value="06:00">
    </td>
    <td>
      <button type="button" class="removebutton">X</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="newdate" id="newdate" value="2017-06-28">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="newtime" id="newtime" value="12:00,12:30,13:00,13:30">
    </td>
    <td>
      <button type="button" class="removebutton">X</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
<tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change id by class. Id is unique. Use find after Closest().

```js
$(document).on('click', 'button.removebutton', function () {
 alpha = $(this).closest('tr').find('.newdate').val();
 alert(alpha);
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="schedule"> 
 <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="newdate" class="newdate" value="2017-06-26">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="newtime" class="newtime" value="06:00">
    </td>
    <td>
      <button type="button" class="removebutton">X</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="newdate" class="newdate" value="2017-06-28">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="newtime" class="newtime" value="12:00,12:30,13:00,13:30">
    </td>
    <td>
      <button type="button" class="removebutton">X</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
<tr>
</table>
```

Comment: if the table happens to be nested within another table, parents() will find multiple `<tr>`s. So it can't be relied on in this scenario. closest() would be a better fit.

Comment: that's true, but in this case there is only one table. Regards

Comment: In the example, yes, but it's only a snippet. You don't know what the rest of the page looks like, or whether this is going to be part of a plugin which could be appended anywhere in another page. It's good practice to make the code as foolproof as it can be.

Comment: @Adisos, thats true but i'm based on what i see. Changed to closest(). Regards

Comment: you should always try to visualise beyond what you can see, and anticipate the things that others don't expect or predict ;-) Sounds like a grand statement, yes? But this example is a good, simple practical application of such a principle.

Comment: Thanks for sharing then. I will apply it later :) Regards

Answer (score 1):

[`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) finds the nearest parent element, `#newdate` is not a parent of the `.removebutton` element. You need the closest `tr` which in this case is the parent of `.removebutton` and then find the `#newdate` element which comes under the same tr as the `.removebutton`.

**Additional Point:** IDs must be unique. So instead of having same Ids, it is better to have classes.

**SOLUTION:**

```js
$(document).on('click', 'button.removebutton', function () {
 alpha = $(this).closest('tr').find('.newdate').val();
 alert(alpha);
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="schedule"> 
 <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="newdate" class="newdate" value="2017-06-26">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="newtime" class="newtime" value="06:00">
    </td>
    <td>
      <button type="button" class="removebutton">X</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="newdate" class="newdate" value="2017-06-28">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="newtime" class="newtime" value="12:00,12:30,13:00,13:30">
    </td>
    <td>
      <button type="button" class="removebutton">X</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
<tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `$(this).closest('tr').find('#newdate').val()`

Check below code:

```js
$(document).on('click', 'button.removebutton', function () {
 alpha = $(this).closest('tr').find('#newdate').val();
 alert(alpha);
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="schedule"> 
 <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="newdate" id="newdate" value="2017-06-26">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="newtime" id="newtime" value="06:00">
    </td>
    <td>
      <button type="button" class="removebutton">X</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="newdate" id="newdate" value="2017-06-28">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="newtime" id="newtime" value="12:00,12:30,13:00,13:30">
    </td>
    <td>
      <button type="button" class="removebutton">X</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
<tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 problems:

1) HTML IDs must be unique, so your second "newdate" element can never be found - JavaScript considers it invalid and will ignore it.

2) `closest()` only searches *up* the DOM, so it will find the tr, but cannot then go back down again to find "newdate".

This should fix it:

```js
$(document).on('click', 'button.removebutton', function() {
  var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
  var alpha = tr.find(".newdate").val();
  alert(alpha);
  tr.remove();
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="schedule">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="newdate" class="newdate" value="2017-06-26">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="newtime" class="newtime" value="06:00">
    </td>
    <td>
      <button type="button" class="removebutton">X</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="newdate" class="newdate" value="2017-06-28">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="newtime" class="newtime" value="12:00,12:30,13:00,13:30">
    </td>
    <td>
      <button type="button" class="removebutton">X</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
</table>
```

Note the use of classes instead of IDs for "newdate" and "newtime", and that we split the process of locating the textbox into two steps - one to find the enclosing `<tr>` by going up the DOM, and a second to search back down from that location for the `.newdate` element.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can use below code but remember never use same id names in different input so you can use class for that and your code is

```js
$(document).on('click', 'button.removebutton', function() {
  alpha = $(this).closest('tr').find(".newdate").val();
  beta = $(this).closest('tr').find(".newtime").val();
  alert(alpha);
  alert(beta);
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="schedule">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="newdate" class="newdate" value="2017-06-26">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="newtime" class="newtime" value="06:00">
    </td>
    <td>
      <button type="button" class="removebutton">X</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="newdate" class="newdate" value="2017-06-28">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="newtime" class="newtime" value="12:00,12:30,13:00,13:30">
    </td>
    <td>
      <button type="button" class="removebutton">X</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
</table>
```

```js
$(document).on('click', 'button.removebutton', function () {
 alpha = $(this).closest('tr #newdate').val();
 alert(alpha);
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="schedule"> 
 <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="newdate" id="newdate" value="2017-06-26">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="newtime" id="newtime" value="06:00">
    </td>
    <td>
      <button type="button" class="removebutton">X</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="newdate" id="newdate" value="2017-06-28">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="newtime" id="newtime" value="12:00,12:30,13:00,13:30">
    </td>
    <td>
      <button type="button" class="removebutton">X</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
<tr>
</table>
```